# MediatR Issue : Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MediatR.IRequestHandler

Tags: c#, .net-core, cqrs, mediatr

I'm using `.Net Core 3.1` and `MediatR` framework/library for query objects.
While executing the webApi\endpoint,  I am getting the below issue

> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating
> the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[Queries.GetOrderResultQuery,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Models.Order.OrdersDto]]
> Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType:
> Queries.Handlers.GetOrderResultQueryHandler': Unable to resolve service for
> type 'Interfaces.Repositories.IOrderResultRepository' while attempting to
> activate 'Queries.Handlers.GetOrderResultQueryHandler'.)

This is my project Structure

[image: ProjectStructure]

1. Microservice.API project is the WebAPI where I have the Controller with endpoints
2. In AppCore project I have the handler `GetOrderResultQueryHandler`
3. In StartUp.cs I have added `services.AddMediatR`

**What I have tried**
I have tried the different options given in the net as below

```
//var mediatRTypes = new Type[] { typeof(AppCore.ServiceAppCore), typeof(Domain.OrderDomain) };
    //services.AddMediatR(mediatRTypes);
    services.AddMediatR(typeof(AppCore.ServiceAppCore),typeof(Domain.OrderDomain));//ServiceAppCore is a class in AppCore Project & OrderDomain is a class in Domain Project where I have Data Models
    //services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup)); // <===Gives Error Handler was not found for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler`
    //services.AddMediatR(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
    //services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
    //services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());// <===Gives Error Handler was not found for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler`
```

For each of the options I get one or the other error mentioned below

1. Handler was not found for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler`
2. Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MediatR.IRequestHandler

I am new to this pattern and am not sure what I am missing here.
Please suggest a resolution for this issue.

Comment: Share the code where you call mediator.Handle(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Persistence project, you will see a RepositoryRegistration class in the Extensions folder.
You should register your repository there like this:

```
public static void AddRepositories(this IServiceCollection services)
{    
    services.AddTransient<IYourRepositoryInterface, YourRepositoryClass>();        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MediatR **IOrderResultRepository** cannot **find it**.
Maybe you forgot to introduce the class you are dependency injecting on.

```
    public static void AddPersistanceServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IOrderResultRepository, YourOrderResultRepositoryClass>();
    }
```

You should not forget to introduce the Injections you have created to the startup.